# COMPLEX SQL / SELECT - INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, join

I would like to construct a complex SQL Query.

Image of the table:

[image]

First, I would like to select all entries WHERE column_1 and column_2 have similar id of each other and WHERE Column_3 is equal to 1.

Thus, it should only return ids: 10000001 and 10000002 and NOT ids: 10000003 and 10000004 because id 10000004 has 2 in column_3 and therefore is not reciprocal of id 10000003.

Second, once ids 10000001 and 10000002 are selected from table_1, I would like to retrieve data from table_2.

Hence, I would like a query that helps me getting table_2.column_2 FROM ids in table_1 WHERE table_1.column_1 AND table_1.column_2 have ids of each other AND table_column_3 is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:
It uses inner join to bring data from same table with comparison of its columns.

```
    select * from table_2
    where column_1
    in
    (
        select a.column_1
        from table_1 a inner join table_1 b on a.column_1=b.column_2 and column_3=1

    )
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think masum7's answer is correct except you will probably need to specify that both a.column_3 and b.column_3 are equal to 1.

I like nested queries. In case you can't or don't want to use them, you can flatten it out like the following example:

```
select t2.column_2
from table_1 as t1a, table_1 as t1b, table_2 as t2
where t1a.column_1 = t1b.column_2 and t1a.column_3 = 1
and t1a.column_2 = t1b.column_1 and t1b.column_3 = 1
and t1a.column_1=t2.column_1;
```

This syntax works in sqlite but may need some tweaking for other databases.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in numerous ways. So far, masum7 vai's solution seems to be the best. However, apart from that, it can be done in the following way as well:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_2 as t2
 WHERE t2.column_1 IN
 (SELECT t1.column_1 FROM table_1 as t1
 WHERE t1.column_1 IN (SELECT t1.column_2 FROM table_1 as t1)
 AND t1.column_3 = 1)
```

A little complex, because I've used subqueries instead of joins. So let me explain.

The first part:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_2 as t2
```

Is going to retrieve **ALL** values from `table_2`.

But then again, you want some **SPECIFIC** data from `table_2` based on some **SPECIFIC** data from `table_1`. So here comes the `WHERE` clause, and a subquery for retrieving data from `table_1`.

The second part:

```
  WHERE t2.column_1 IN
  (SELECT t1.column_1 FROM table_1 as t1
  WHERE t1.column_1 IN (SELECT t1.column_2 FROM table_1 as t1)
  AND t1.column_3 = 1)
```

Can be broken into further sub parts.

Sub part - 1:

```
  SELECT t1.column_1 FROM table_1 as t1
```

Is going to retrieve **ALL** values of `column_1` of `table_1`.

But, that's not what you want. You want **SPECIFICALLY**:

a. Those values of `column_1` which are present in `column_2` and,
 
   b. At the same time, those values of `column_1` for which `column_3` value is 1.

Based on these 2 points, comes sub part 2.

Sub part - 2:

```
  WHERE t1.column_1 IN (SELECT t1.column_2 FROM table_1 as t1)
  AND t1.column_3 = 1)
```

The first `WHERE` condition says `column_1` values must be present inside the nested subquery which has all `column_2` values. The second one says, corresponding `column_3` value must be 1.

Hope this query retrieves your expected result, and that you understood my explanation of the query. Good luck and have a nice day! Wish you a good journey in StackOverflow. :)

**EDIT-1**:

Just a small addition to the query. I forgot to add a `GROUP BY` clause. It should be `GROUP BY` `t2.column_1`.

So the modified query becomes:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_2 as t2
 WHERE t2.column_1 IN
 (SELECT t1.column_1 FROM table_1 as t1
 WHERE t1.column_1 IN (SELECT t1.column_2 FROM table_1 as t1)
 AND t1.column_3 = 1)
 GROUP BY t2.column_1
```

Sorry I missed it out. :)